# Why can this kind of statement work in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, language-features

```
$user->Phonenumbers[]->phonenumber = '123 123';
$user->Phonenumbers[]->phonenumber = '456 123';
$user->Phonenumbers[]->phonenumber = '123 777';
```

I've never seen this kind of syntax

**EDIT**

This seems more probably a feature,do you guys know how can I implement a feature like this?

Comment: Anything more specific? What part of the syntax haven't you seen?

Comment: I guess it's the Phonenumbers[]->phonenumber part

Comment: Does this actually not throw an error? :o Could you maybe offer a bit more of the code, especially the definition of `Phonenumbers` in the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that something like the following creates an *stdClass* object with the property *phonenumber* and pushes it into the `$user->Phonenumbers` array:

```
$user->Phonenumbers[]->phonenumber = 12345;
```

I’ve never seen that syntax too.

Comment: If Phonenumbers is an array, how can you use the `->` notation on that? Compare to `$foo = array(); $foo->test = 12345;` results in a warning.

Comment: Oh,maybe it's not a syntax,hopefully a feature,can you figure out how to implement this kind of feature?

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: `[]` is used on the array. But I don’t know why `[]->` is creating a new object.

Comment: @ORM: Where did you find this?

Comment: I've posted a working example of this. But I have never seen this before either.

Comment: Interesting syntax too. I didn't know the stdClass could be instanced that way. I'm curious -how- and -why- this works.

Comment: This even works without an array, when just accessing a property with object `->` syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Gumbo is right, here is a working example:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public $arr = array();
    public $obj = null;
}
$a = new Test();
$a->arr[]->foo = 1234;
$a->arr[]->bar = 'test';
var_dump( $a->arr );

// even more weird on null objects
$a->obj->foobar = 'obj was null!';
var_dump( $a->obj );
```

returns:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    int(1234)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["bar"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
}
object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
  ["foobar"]=>
  string(13) "obj was null!"
}
```

**edit:** Okay, I found something related in the php manual about this:

> If an object is converted to an object, it is not modified. If a value of any other type is converted to an object, a new instance of the stdClass built-in class is created. If the value was NULL, the new instance will be empty. *([source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php))*

So using the `->` syntax converts the *thing* into an object. In the example above `$obj` is *null*, so a new, empty instance is created, and the `foobar` member is set.

When looking at the array example, `arr[]` first creates a new (empty) array element, which is then converted into an empty object because of the `->` syntax and the member variable is set.

Comment: This is amazing!Can you explain why?

Comment: Given that it even works with null objects (2nd part of the example), it does make sense, that the array creation with `[]` results in this. But I don't know why you can even access a non-existing object and create it on-the-fly with that.

Comment: Will raise an E_STRICT notice though: *Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value*

Comment: *Converting NULL to an array results in an empty array.* See http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php - so basically, PHP converts NULL by operator context.

Answer (score 2):

php "implicitly" creates arrays and objects when using [] and -> operators on undefined variables.

```
 $does_not_exist->foo = 1;
```

here php creates a stdclass object and throws an "strict" warning "Creating default object from empty value". The similar thing with arrays

```
 $does_not_exist[] = 1;
```

oddly works without a warning, which some people [consider](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg08381.html) to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will typecast `NULL` to the context in which it is used.

```
var_dump( (bool) NULL );
var_dump( (int) NULL );
var_dump( (float) NULL );
var_dump( (string) NULL );
var_dump( (array) NULL );
var_dump( (object) NULL );
```

will give

```
bool(false)
int(0)
float(0)
string(0) ""
array(0) {}
object(stdClass)#1 (0) {}
```

Consequently, when doing:

```
$a = NULL;
$a[] = NULL;       // used in array context `[]`
$a[0]->foo = NULL; // object context `->`
$a[0]->foo++;      // number context `++`
```

the resulting structure will be

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Like I mentioned in the comments, doing so is against `E_STRICT` standards though and will raise a notice.